# Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer on playing next song

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I play the first song then it's absolutely fine but next time I get the error message of title text and I got the error in `mPlayer.prepare()`, please extend your help...

```
mPlayer.reset();
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this); mPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
mPlayer.prepare(); mPlayer.start(); isPlaying = true;
playPauseBtn.setEnabled(true); navigationbar.setEnabled(true);
totalMediaTime = mPlayer.getDuration() / 1000;
durationTextView.setText(Helper.getTimeFromSecods(totalMediaTime));
navigationbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
```

and I get error code 38... No idea what's it..

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get mediaPlayer.getDuration() before the preparation is complete. Use the setOnPreparedListener() method to set a preparation listener and call the getDuration() method only after the preparation is complete.